# What should I override onTouchEvent() or onTouchListener() in Android?

Tags: android, touch-event

Hi in game programming in android where I draw things to the screen in a different thread using a SurfaceView, in order to receive touch events, should I override the onTouchEvent() method, or onTouchListener() from the View.onTouchListener interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't really matter, as both can do the same job. However overriding onTouchEvent results in more concise code, as you don't have to supply an implementation of a listener.

Comment: As I mentioned, it doesn't really matter, even performance-wise, because your listener would be instantiated only once anyway, when the activity starts.